# How to simulate landscape orientation in the android simulator?

Tags: android, adt

How can I simulate landscape orientation in the android simulator?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try hitting ctrl+F12 :)

Answer (score 2):

what do you mean by Horizontal simulation? If you are talking about activity orientation then either you can define that in AndroidManifest xml file like this:

```
<activity ....
android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
```

Or if you want to do in the code then you can request orientation on your activity object:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: yes, but when i am testing in the simulator, is there any way to turn my virtual device to landscape so I can test it properly?

Comment: if you are on mac the try pressing Fn+Ctrl+F12.

Comment: bhups, that is exactly what im looking for. THanks!